# Pandas: Any() All() with if/else

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a simple if/else statement on a Pandas dataframe. I was getting the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.` so I tried using `any() all()`. Using these options causes only the `if` or `else` part of the expression to evaluate. My data looks like this:

```
state       district    democrat    republican  totalvotes  votestowin  rwasted
Maine       1           227546.0    164569.0    392115.0    196057.5    -31488.5
Maine       2           159081.0    192878.0    351959.0    175979.5     16898.5
Maryland    1           103622.0    242574.0    346196.0    173098.0    69476.0
Maryland    2           192183.0    102577.0    294760.0    147380.0    -44803.0
Maryland    3           214640.0    115048.0    329688.0    164844.0    -49796.0
```

My code is

```
for idx,row in data.iterrows():
    if (data['democrat'] >= data['republican']).all():
        data['rwasted'] = data['republican']
    else:
        data['rwasted'] = data['republican'] - data['votestowin']
```

You can see it's only evaluating the `else` part of the code. Any ideas how to get this working? Also why is it returning an error in the first place? This expression seems pretty straightfoward to me.

Comment: The equation `data['democrat'] >= data['republican']` isn't `True` for several rows in your dataframe, hence `.all()` will evaluate to `False`. *Only* if the equation holds for *all* rows will it be `True`.

Comment: The `.all()` function will check if all entries of `democrat` are greater than `republican` in the entire dataframe. This is not what you are trying to check

Comment: Notice that you're iterating over the rows, yet you don't use any of those rows individually: each iteration of the loop, you access the full DataFrame instead. You'll have to rethink how you're working with DataFrames, otherwise you'll be working against them. Your current loop suggests you're using them like dicts, which they are not.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for that explanation. That really helped me understand what the underlying problem is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a mask:

```
# Set a default value
data['rwasted'] = data['republican'] - data['votestowin']
# Find where it is different
mask = data['democrat'] >= data['republican']
# Set those rows to another value
data['rwasted'][mask] = data['republican']
```

No if-else statement needed, *no* for loop needed either. You have to think row- and column-wise with DataFrames, not cell-like.

Comment: Definitely good to highlight that the way to approach dataframes is row and column wise. The one thing I would note is that `mask` here is a `pd.Series` that is comprised of boolean values as that might not be apparent to OP

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for answering and explaining why it wasn't originally working :)

Answer (score 1):

`.all()` is a function that applies to an entire `Series`, not a single `row`. You are mixing concepts here. To do a row-by-row comparison (as you want to do):

```
myseries = []
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['democrat'] >= row['republican']:
        myseries.append(row['republican'])
    else:
        myseries.append(row['republican'] - row['votestowin'])

data['rwasted'] = pd.Series(myseries)
```

See @9769953's answer for a more concise way to apply it in the dataframe, but this is the analogue to your `iterrows` approach

Comment: Gotcha, I see. Thanks for finagling a way for it to work!